# Is there a way to convert some XML files in the directory to AVRO FILES?

Tags: xml, json, parsing, xml-parsing, avro

Is there a way to convert some XML files in the directory to AVRO FILES??

So, the data in the XML files would be read and corresponding similar AVRO files would be made and serialized at one end ... And deserialized at the other to get the data.

Are there some parsers or something which could help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems.
You should have a look at [this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/AVROSchemaJAXB). You can also check this [github repository](https://github.com/Nokia/Avro-Schema-Generator).
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Generate Avro schema and Avro binary from XSD schema and XML https://github.com/stealthly/xml-avro